# Java servlet opens file with the wrong file path

Tags: java, xml, servlets, get, filenotfoundexception

I have a servlet that uses another class for reading .XML file, here is the servlet simple `doGet()` :

```
private checkDBStatus;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      checkDBStatus = new checkDBStatus();
      String returnText = checkDBStatus.getText();
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Actual logic goes here.
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println(returnText);
  }
```

The file path in `checkDBStatus` is `XMLS/DB.xml`, when running on a Java class like `Program`(main) `checkDBStatus` works fine with the right path, but when a `Get` request is handled in servlet class I get `FileNotFoundException` with file path `\IBM\SDP\XMLS\DB.xml` (this directory was not found in my file system as well, I have IBM RAD).
Anyone had encounter this problem?
Here is the code that reads thr .xml:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("XMLS/DB.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile); // the rest is just parsing...
```

Comment: Can you post the code where it reads the xml file? You schould trying to debug checkDBStatus where it try to read the xml file..

Comment: Posting the code inside getText.

Comment: XMLS/DB.xml is a **relative** file path. So it looks for a file XMLS/DB.xml from the **current** firectory. The current directory is the directory from which the java command used to stert your web server was executed. Using a relative file path is a bad idea. Use an absolute file path if the data should really be loaded from the file system, or embed it with your app, and use Class.getResourceAsStream() or ServletContext.getResourceAsStream().

Comment: is DB.xml in your project resources directory in folder XMLS? If yes you schould use here getResource, so you can get the full path to create the File

Comment: is your `XMLS` directory in webcontent Folder or any where else? is your project uses maven based build or any other?

Comment: @JBNizet - trying and posting the result, sgpalit - yes its on the project directory, Vikrant Kashyap - No, its on the project directory and I dont use Maven.